# select comma separated foreign keys and print names against them in same comma separated pattern

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

### product table

```
product_id    make_id       model_id
1              139,22         42,56
```

---

### make table:

```
make_id      make_name
  139          honda 
   22          toyota
```

---

### model table:

```
model_id      model_name
   42           civic
   56           corolla
```

---

I want result in two variables for product_id=1

```
$make = honda,toyota
$model= civic,corolla
```

I have tried it in many ways, like retrieving data in string and tried explicit it and than use joins to make view and use that data in my variables, but I can not get it done. I am new to mysql and its giving me hard time even though it could be easy one for all of you.

Comment: Instead of putting comma-separated lists into fields and completely breaking normalization, use a many-to-many table structure.

Comment: i have scenario where i can not change the structure of the table. all i want to show make and model that were assigned to this specific product. i thought i will retrieve the make and model fields into string and than use joins to get their names from respective tables. is it possible in that way?